# Achieve fixed column number of a table with data-binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, html-table

I have a table with bound data ([KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/)) like this:

```
...
<tr>

 <th class="rotated">Row 1</th>               
 <!-- ko foreach: Dog-->            
  <td>
     <p data-bind="text: Name">
     </p>
  </td>
 <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
...
```

Problem is that I'd like to have fixed number of columns, for example 5, but sometimes there isn't much data so there are less than 5 columns generated. I'd like to know what is the best way how to add the columns so they are always 5.

I made a Javascript function which goes through all the rows, counts the `<td>` tags and add `<td>` tags if needed. Is there other option?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use an array with 5 items even though it has empty values in it.

For example:

```
 var Dog = [{Name:"dog1"},{Name:"dog2"},{Name:""},{Name:"dog3"},{Name:""}];
```